# Integrate MHTabBarController in App

Tags: ios, iphone

I wanted to integrate `MHTabBarController` in my app .When I try to import MHTabBarController.h and MHTabBarController.m files it created problem. It showing me lots of error.

So how to use `MHTabBarController` in app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) download MTTabBarController
2) Copy "MHTabBarController" and paste it to your project.
 
3) Goto build phases and add following libraries 
   UiKit,foundation and core graphics framework.
4) the go to "MHTabBarController.h" and add import Uikit framework 
  like this #import

5) clean the project and build

you are good to go.

Comment: yes done solved my issue thanks:)